# Capturing Impacted Row Counts after OLE DB Command (SSIS)

Tags: ssis

I have an OLE DB Command in a Data Flow that deletes records based on results from a Lookup Task.  I want to get a count of the number of records deleted.  I set up a RowCount task after the OLE DB Command but the result I receive is the number of records that match the Lookup, not the number of records that match the criteria in the delete statement(OLE DB Command).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

-Craig

Comment: I'd say to multicast your flow before the delete command, then add a "Conditional Split" with the same criteria as your "OLE DB Command" on one end and count that output.(which should be exacly the amount of records to be deleted)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a null placeholder column for your row count in your data flow. You can add it as a derived column or in your source query. Let's call it **rowsDeleted**.
2. Create a stored procedure to process your deletion. I've created a simplified version for a made-up table:

   **create procedure deleteTT @id int, @rowcount int OUTPUT 
   as 
   begin 
   delete from dbo.tt where a = @id;
   SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
   end**
3. Set the SqlCommand of your OLE DB Command to the following: **exec deleteTT ?,  ? output**;
4. In the Column Mappings tab, map your id column from your lookup to the @id parameter, and map rowsDeleted to the @rowcount OUTPUT parameter.
5. Now rowsDeleted is part of your data flow for that row and you can do with it as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to try to get the Command object to emit the count of what is deleted and then wire up an aggregate to it to sum all those values.

I've never had much success getting output out of the Command component so I'd cheat and either compute the aggregate in the preceding lookup and add that value into the stream or just use a Script Component to fire the delete statement and capture the `@@rowcount` value and push it into the Data flow.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I knew it couldn't be an easy fix.  What is the syntax to capture the @@rowcount value?

Comment: Can I assign @@ROWCOUNT to a SSIS variable in order to display in a log?  If so, what is the syntax?